# How to make this Vue.js component to work?

Tags: vue.js

I have this component with default data that I want to reuse on other pages with other data:

#### CustomCard.vue

```html
<template>
   <div>

      <v-layout >
         <v-flex md4 class="white">

            <div>  
               <slot class="top-img">
                  <img src="../assets/default.jpg" alt="">
               </slot>

               <slot class="description">
                  <p>default description</p>
               </slot>
            </div>

         </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

#### Page1.vue

```html
<template>
   <div>

     <custom-card>
     </custom-card>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

### Question:

What should I do in order to use **CustomCard.vue** component on **Page1.vue** page with another data:

- `src="../assets/image1.jpg"`
- `"changed description"`

Answer (score 2):

You should import the component *CustomCard* in the component where you want to use it, and then add it in components option from your vue object.
After this you are ready to use it in your template.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <custom-card/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomCard from './components/CustomCard' . // <-- This

export default {
  components: {
    CustomCard // <--This
  }
}
```

If you want to use different data... you can pass them by props like this:

```
<custom-card :data="newData"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the "newData" is a bunch of tags. how do you put it all in the  `:data=` attribute? I think I have to use slots, but for some reason just adding a div with `slot="slotName"` attribute on the page, doesn't work, I still see the "default description" from the component

Comment: if the date is html elements, then better go with slots. This is the slot purpose at the end.